# Trigger Handler twice in Applescript results in error

Tags: applescript

so i written this code so far, it works very well, the only issue is, calling the code twice results with an error «script» doesn’t understand the Remi message. (-1708)

Whats to point here and how can i unset the handler after it was triggered?

The Code:

```
my Remi()

on Remi()
    set cD to (current date)

    tell application "Reminders"
        --set output to name of reminders
        if (count of (reminders whose completed is false)) > 0 then
            set output to ""
            set todoList to name of reminders whose completed is false
            repeat with itemNum from 1 to ((count of (reminders whose completed is false)))
                try
                    set Remi to item itemNum of reminders
                    set remiT to due date of Remi
                    set tim to time string of remiT
                    set dD to date string of remiT
                    set nN to name of Remi
                    if remiT ≤ cD then
                        set val to (tim & " - " & nN & " $$" & dD & "/ENDE")
                        set output to (output & val & return)
                    end if
                end try
            end repeat
        else
            set output to "No reminders available"
        end if
    end tell
    return output
end Remi
```

Thx for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what is causing the problem. You have a variable "Remi" inside the "Remi()" handler. I guess you can't do that! So either change the name of the variable or the name of the handler and you should be good.

Comment: Your code gives me the same error fanaugen so my answer remains. Are you saying your code works for you? Remember that the error starts on the second run of the code. I'm running this on 10.8.2.

Comment: Thx a lot, the double variable issue REMI was the resin, once i changed to Handlers Name to something different, it just works, so thx a lot

Comment: I'm glad it works for you Serge. Please mark this answer as the answer to your question so others can see that it has been answered.

Comment: @regulus6633 you're right, sorry. The error really occurs on the second run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `set Remi to item itemNum of reminders` statement which changes the value of the `remi` global variable from a handler to whatever `item itemNum of reminders' turns out to be.  The second time through, when you ask AppleScript to call the Remi handler, it is no longer handler and so the call fails.

You can change your code to not alter the global `Remi` variable, or you can declare `Remi` local within the handler using a `local Remi` statement.  This protects the global version of Remi from alteration.