# Cannot call loaded script object handler twice. Why?

Tags: applescript

I am thoroughly stumped by this problem. I have some standard functions that I saved in a compiled AppleScript file, let's call it `functions.scpt`. In another script, I use `load script` to load a script object to `functions.scpt`:

```
set funcs to load script "path/to/functions.scpt
```

I have one handler in `functions.scpt` called `icon()`. For whatever reason, if I try to call this function more than once in my other script, I get an error. Here's some quick example code:

```
--called once
funcs's icon()
--called twice
funcs' icon()
```

Whenever I do this, I get the following error: `error "«script» doesn’t understand the “icon” message." number -1708 from «script» to «class icon»`.

Why can't I call the same function from a loaded script object twice? How can I fix this? I need to call it multiple times.

Comment: Without seeing at least one of the handlers in the functions script, it's a little hard to diagnose. I would want to make sure the script uses the correct format. However, I get a clue from «class icon», which tells me you may be using a keyword you shouldn't be. Try changing the name of the handler (sorry, they're called handlers in AS) to something else, like iconDoer()

Comment: You CAN call a handler from a script object multiple times. I just tested and works fine with 'icon' as handler name as well. You must reduce your code down to identify the error. Post the icon handler or simply can't help you.

Comment: I'll echo @jweaks -- please post more code.  Also, you might try making func a property, a la `property func: (load script "path:to:functions.scpt")` (notice also that I'm using the correct Mac separator : instead of /)

Comment: Good point. I should have posted my actual code. It was long, and I thought the abstraction would be enough. Now I know. And I found the answer, as noted below. But thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @[CRGreen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2092796/crgreen) and @[jweaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3097556/jweaks). I actually just found the answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256042/2884386

I had set a variable `icon` within the handler, which was overwriting the handler. So when the other script tried to access it the second time, it wasn't pointing to the handler, but to the variable. I rewrote the internal variables, and that fixed it.

So, this is (as an example) correct:

```
on icon()
    set _icon to "path/to/icon.png"
    return POSIX file _icon
end icon
```

Whereas this is incorrect:

```
on icon()
    set icon to "path/to/icon.png
    return POSIX file icon
end icon
```

Comment: That was actually my suspicion, that your handler adjusted the icon object in the script.

Comment: Yes. In hindsight, a rookie mistake. It was lazy scripting on my part :(